# Abrir segundo modal somente após fechamento do primeiro

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal

Parece simples mas to com dificuldades, tenho dois `modal` que tem que aparecer na home após login do usuário, preciso que apareça um e somente depois que o usuário fechar esse primeiro apareça o segundo modal. Tenho o seguinte código:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#ModalUpdateData").modal("hide");

  setTimeout(function(){
    if (!Cookies.get("ModalScore")){
      $("#ModalScore").modal("show");
      Cookies.set("ModalScore", true);
    } else {

    }
  },3000);
  
  setTimeout(function(){
    if (!Cookies.get("ModalUpdateData")){
      $("#ModalUpdateData").modal("show");
      Cookies.set("ModalUpdateData", true);
    } else {

    }
  },3000);
});
```

Qual a melhor solução para isso?  Ja tentei o `.on('click')`no elemento `#ModalScore (primeiro modal)` porem no ele tem um slide aonde eu clico dentro dele para mudar de slide e acaba fazendo o outro modal aparecer.

Comment: Vc pode startar o segundo a partir do click de fechamento do 1º...

Comment: Quais plugins está utilizando? Qual modal?

Comment: @MagicHat então mas o primeiro fecha tanto clicando no 'x' ou fora do modal.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic cara uso o modal do bootstrap mesmo.

Comment: qual a versão do bootstrap ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seguinte pode usar a função de eventos do próprio `bootstrap`:

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
  // abre o outro modal  aqui...
})
```

Retirei daqui tem outras info se precisar [fonte](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/modal/#events)

Comment: Gênio exatamente isso =D  simples e fácil e eu quebrando a cabeça.

Comment: Boas, se alguma das questões estiverem corretas considere validá-las clicando no icon verde abaixo as setas de avaliações(bah!! as 2 tão certas e são iguais..hahah escolhe uma depois abraço)...

Comment: Escolhi já, como a sua foi primeiro e eu ja tinha escolhido ela. Obrigado de novo.

Comment: +1 também as soluções foram postadas ao mesmo tempo, mas, o que vale é ser objetivo e claro ... !!! vlw

Answer (score 2):

Utilize `hidden.bs.modal`, ou seja, `$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) { });` é o evento que significa o fechar do modal e nele chama o próximo modal com `$("#myModal2").modal('show');`

```js
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
  // do something...
  $("#myModal2").modal('show');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title 1</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>MODAL 1</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title 2</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>MODAL 2</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

<sup>***Referencias:***</sup>

- [Bootstrap modals](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)
- [Bootstrap modals-events](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events)

Comment: A sua já vem até com HTML +1...

Comment: Obrigado man era isso mesmo, tinha visto a do @MagicHat antes e tinha conseguido a sua resposta é igual porem ja com HTML, obrigado =D

Comment: Sem problemas @Erick